# What was Spyro and Cynder's relationship originally?

Tags: video-games, spyro

Jared Pullen confirmed Spyro and Cynder weren't originally supposed to be a couple they were made a canon couple due to popularity. But what was Cynder supposed to be if not a love interest? Some people have speculated that she was his sister especially because the GBA version of Legend of Spyro Eternal Night said that they were "siblings".

However, I read on other sources that this was a mistake by Amaze studios so are they really siblings, just friends, or was Cynder meant to be a villain?

Answer (score 2):

Cynder was originally going to simply be the game series' primary antagonist. The idea of making her into Spyro's love interest was a fan-driven addition to future games. The reboot trilogy's Lead Concept Artist, Jared Pullen does acknowledge that it was a fairly obvious [*ship*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shipping_(fandom))).

> **Q:** (...)*"everyone I know seems to believe she ends up with Spyro in some romantic manner...." Are you hinting that she doesn't really?*
>
> **A:** *hehe, no its more that them getting together wasn't a thing we'd intended originally - it's pretty much something that emerged from fan conversations... like I've marveled at with appreciation now for years: Cynder and Spyro have a life all their own. They've grown up, flown the coop, and have nested comfortably :) Seeing the fans delight in wanting Spyro and Cynder to get together prompted me and the team to consider it.... it only seems natural to me. I think it's now common-place belief (if not unwritten lore) that they are an item. It's the way I would have eventually gone with it.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Q/A with Jared Pullen, lead concept artist of TLoS](https://www.deviantart.com/dragonoficeandfire/journal/Q-A-with-Jared-Pullen-lead-concept-artist-of-TLoS-591799120)</sup></sub>

Notably, they were not intended to be *siblings*, although they were born in the same year. The reference to them (as such) in the Eternal Night literature was simply an error.

> **[Chris Wilson](https://spyro.fandom.com/wiki/Christopher_Wilson):** *I am part of The Legend of Spyro production team here at Sierra and I noticed that there was some question as to whether Spyro and Cynder were meant to be siblings and the answer is 'no'. If in any of the Eternal Night releases it suggests that they are related, it was an oversight and purely unintentional. Though Spyro and Cynder were both born in the Year of the Dragon and are from the same batch of eggs, they are not meant to be brother and sister. I aplogize if there was any confusion on this matter and I hope that you are all enjoying the latest entry in the series. We do read your comments and we really appreciate all of your feedback and dedication. Happy gaming!*
>
> <sub><sup>[VGA Games Forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20080122000949/http://forums.vgames.com/message.jspa?messageID=609164)</sup></sub>